# Einstein Bot after-hours support

Tags: einstein, chat, bots

I'm trying to get Einstein bot to display a closed message when someone asks to be transfered to a human and we're outside the hours of 9-5 and/or no agents are available.

Right now, if someone asks to be transfered and no agents are available, it abruptly ends the chat and states 'no agents available'. I'd like it to display a closed message w. a link to our contact page or email.

Has anyone else had this issue an figured out a way to resolve it? I tried adding a variable or entity but can't seem to find one for 'agent available'

[image: transfer w/ no closed message]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dialog to use as a 'No Agents' available message and add your message including your 'Contact Us' page and/or email. Once you've created the dialog, use the drop down button to the right of the dialog name (dialog settings) and select 'Set as No Available Agents'.

When someone selects or is directed to 'Transfer to Agent', it'll display that message if there aren't agents available.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on the similar problem. Here's the approach that we followed.

Create a custom Business Hours for you support team if needed or use the default Business Hours for you org.

When the 'Transfer to Agent' dialog is initiated you can invoke an Apex Action that would check whether the current time is within business hours or outside of your configured business hours. Return the appropriate response from Apex, and use that to show the relevant message.